# getting typescript error on avatar upload

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'am using adonisJs as framework and i have problem with typescript when i trying to build project.

```
const avatar = ctx.request.file('avatar')
    if (avatar) {
      const avatarFileName = `avatar-${avatar.clientName}.${avatar.extname}`
      await avatar.moveToDisk(`./`, {
        visibility: 'public',
        name: avatarFileName,
      })
      payload.avatar = await Drive.getUrl(avatarFileName)
    }
```

this is my avatar upload code and am getting error on playload.avatar
it's telling me that " Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MultipartFileContract'.ts(2322) " can someone help me fixing this error : )

Comment: I think you need to define  type of file

Comment: And how can i do that? : )